# Express a set as boolean function

Tags: combinatorics, binary-operations

HD = Hamming distance

For a 4-bit string = x, I want to be able to express ALL other binary bit strings in a set that is a multiple of certain HD (in this example say 2) away from x AND at least that certain HD away from each other in the set.

For say "0000", the set would be {1100,0110,0011,1001,0101,1010,1111}

The first 6 bits strings are easy: 4C2 = 6 combinations, but selecting the last bit string {1111} is tricky. If the required HD=2, then the number of elements in the set would be 4C2+4C(2+2)=7; hence multiple of the HD.

The trick is that these elements: {1110,1101,0111,1011} can not be in the above set as they are an HD=1 away from the element {1111}. One of the rules is that all the elements in the set have to be at least the stated HD away from each other. These elements {0001,1000,....} also can't be in the set as they contradict the other rule which is they are HD<2 than 0000.

Again, I want to express this set as a boolean function for n bit strings.

Comment: Here's one way to express this function: 
$$\begin{align} & f(x_1x_2x_3x_4)
\\ & =x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4+x_1x_3+x_1x_4 
\\ &+x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4 
\\ &+x_1x_2x_3x_4 \end{align}$$

Where $+$ refers to XOR (or mod 2 addition). Then, 

$$f(0000)=0, f(1000)=0, f(1100)=1, f(1110)=0, f(1111)=1$$

Comment: Then if you want to define this function for an arbitrary $x$ you can. $g_x(v)=f(v+x)$ should do the trick. 

Is this the type of thing you are looking for?

Comment: I was actually looking for a boolean expression in terms of n, where n represents both even and odd bit strings. This is also an answer but restricted to 4-bit strings; I want to express for n(=4,5,6,etc) bit strings. Thanks.

Comment: @Mason may I ask why you added (x1x2x3 +  x1x2x4  +  x1x3x4  +  x2x3x4) as these elements are not present in the set? I may have missed sth.

Comment: This is the result of the multiplication 
$$\bigg(1+x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\bigg)\bigg(1+(1+x_1)(1+x_2)(1+x_3)(1+x_4) \bigg)$$

If this looks tedious: This is less of a pain to multiply when you know:
 
$x_i(1+x_i)=0$ and $x_i^2=x_i$

Also: $\prod_{n\in A}(1+x_n) =\sum_{S\subset A} \prod_{n\in S} x_n$ .

Comment: Thank you. May I ask you to take a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3675103/general-combinatorics-formula

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in \{0,1 \}^n$ be a binary string of length $n$ and $|x|$ denote the number of nonzero entries in $x$.  Take $E= \{ \vec{v}\in \{ 0,1\}^n : |\vec{v}| \equiv 0 \mod 2 \}$ and $E^*=E \setminus \{\vec{0}\}$. We want to construct a function $f: \{0,1\}^n\to \{0,1\} $ such that $f(E^*)=1$ and $f(\{0,1\}^n \setminus E^*)=0$. The following function should do the trick:

$$f(\vec{x})= \bigg(1+\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \bigg) \bigg(1+\prod_{i=1}^n(x_i+1)\bigg)$$

Where addition and multiplication are performed mod $2$.

The first part of acts as indicator of parity of $|x|$.

$$1+\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \cases{0 \mbox{ when $|x|$ is odd}  \\1 \mbox{ when $|x|$ is even}}$$

And the second part acts an indicator of whether $x=\vec{0}$

$$1+\prod_{i=1}^n(x_i+1)=\cases{0 \mbox{ when } x = \vec{0} \\1 \mbox{ when } x\ne \vec{0}}$$

Comment: I'm not sure this is the simplest formulation but it does describe the function.