# General combinatorics formula

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

HD = Hamming distance; this question is an extension to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673763/express-a-set-as-boolean-function).

For an example 4-bit string, I want to be able to express ALL binary bit strings in a set that are a multiple of certain HD (in this example say 2) from each other in the set.

For 4 bit strings, the **correct set** would be {0000,1100,0110,0011,1001,0101,1010,1111}

My understanding of the combinatorics formula is 4C0+4C2+4C4=8 elements as above.

But when I follow the same formula for 4-bit strings, HD=3, it comes to 4C0+4C3 = 5 elements which are wrong: {0000,0111,1011,1101,1110}. As you can see only 0000 is an HD=3 away from other elements.
I want this set {0000,1110} as they are uniquely an HD=3 away from each other.

Is there any way to generalize this number of combinations in the set through combinatorics/any formula for n bit strings?

EDIT:

All these are correct for HD=3: {0000,0111} or {0000,1011} etc. as long as all the elements are an HD=3n ( n >= 1,2...) away from each other.

For say 6 bits, these would be the correct set for HD=3:  { 000000, **000111**, **111000**, 111111 } because the number of elements = 6C0+ **2 (I don't know how to express this with combinatorics)**  + 6C6

Comment: "all binary bit strings in a set that is a multiple of certain HD from each other in the set" doesn't seem to make sense – is there a typo?

Comment: In the given example, for the **correct set** of HD=2, all the bit strings present are an HD of multiple of 2n away from each other where n>=0,1,2 .... hence "a multiple of certain HD from......". I feel it's right. But can't generalize when HD=3.

Comment: "I want this set {0000,1110} as they are uniquely an HD=3 away from each other."  Why is it this one and not {0000,0111}, for example?

Comment: All these are correct for HD=3: {0000,0111} or {0000,1011} etc. as long as all the elements are an HD=3n ( n >= 0,1,2...) away from each other.

For say 6 bits, these would be the correct set for HD=3:  { 000000, **000111**, **111000**, 111111 } because the number of elements = 6C0+ **(I don't know how to express this with combinatorics) 2**  + 6C6

Comment: @zzzzzazaza: Indeed, "the bit strings are" a multiple of a distance of each other, but that sentence says "bit strings in a set that is a multiple of certain HD from each other" – it seems that perhaps you mean "are" where it says "is"?

Comment: @joriki Yes Sorry I thought you were focussing on the "multiple". I corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: There is a linkage between XOR and even/odd because the XOR of two numbers with an even number of bits has an even number of bits, as does the XOR of two numbers with an odd numbers of bits.  When you look for a HD of $3$ you lose this linkage because you can XOR two numbers at a distance of $3$ from a given number and get one at a distance of $1$.  If you start with $000000$ and note that $000111$ and $011100$ are both at distance $3$, their XOR is $000100$.

Comment: @RossMillikan "If you start with 000000 and note that 000111 and 011100 are both at distance 3, their XOR is 000100"--------but I am trying to find a set so that all the HDs between them are a certain distance apart; why am I comparing HD with just 000000?

Comment: @joriki Do you think it is possible to generalize it?

Comment: I used 000000 as a convenient starting point.  You can use any bit string you want and XOR it with all the elements in the set.  000000 is handy to help see what is going on in terms of how many 1 bits each word has.

Comment: @RossMillikan I need those XOR values between all the elements in the set to be **exactly** HD=3n  (n>=1,2....) so 011100 won't be in the set. The correct set would be { 000000, 000111, 111000, 111111 }. Maybe I am missing the point you are making.

Comment: @zzzzzazaza: I'm not sure why you're pinging me about that – you already asked that in the question, and as you know, I read the question. If I have something to say about it, I will.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have $n$ bits and want distance $3$, you need $n$ to be a multiple of $3$.  You just divide the bits into blocks of $3$ bits and turn on or off each block.  You will get $2^{n/3}$ words, each with a multiple of $3$ bits turned on, and each a Hamming Distance a multiple of $3$ from each other.  For example, with $n=9$ we might have the words
$000000000\\
111000000,000111000,000000111\\
111111000,111000111,000111111\\
111111111$

Comment: Will this 2^(n/3) formula for the number of codewords hold true for all odd numbers of **HD**s(3,5,7.....)? Or for just HD=3?

Comment: It would be $2^{n/k}$ where $k$ is the HD.  You just have all the binary numbers from $0$ through $2^{n/k}$, then replicate each bit $k$ times.

Comment: Thank you. And for n bit strings' even numbers of **HD**s do you think my formula is correct?

For 4-bit strings, HD=2, 4C0+4C2+4C4
For 5-bit strings, HD=2, 5C0+5C2+5C4
For 6-bit strings, HD=4, 6C0+6C4
For 8-bit strings, HD=4, 8C0+8C4+8C8

Comment: No.  For six bit strings, $6C4$ accepts $111100$ and $111001$ which are only at a distance of $2$ from each other.  HD=2 is special because of its relationship with XOR.  For larger numbers you just need to replicate the bits as I said above.

Comment: So basically you are saying that only for HD=2, the summation of [n C (0,2,4....)] will work, and other than that when HD>=3 doesn't matter if it's odd or even I have to replicate the bits?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: When n is not a multiple of k it seems this formula doesn't work.

Comment: You can just ignore the last bits, so you round $n/k$ down and leave the remainder always $0$